# Is there a way to store the idle time in a .txt file using lua scripting? Or maybe consult it in real time with VBS?

Tags: vbscript, lua, mouseevent, keyboard-events

*Note: What I mean by 'idle time' is the fraction of milliseconds when keyboard and mouse are not being used.*

Basically what I'm trying here at work is to avoid a script to activate itself while someone is currently using the computer, in my specific case (considering the softwares and scripts used here in my company) I believe the best way of doing that would be using a lua script to store what we could call 'idle-time' in a text file or consulting it in VBS. One way of doing it is that whenever someone move the cursor or use a key a counter (re)initiate itself. Can we do that using .lua? Or possibly something similar with VBS?

Comment: I am not aware of any way to do this using Lua, but AHK might help you if you can learn that :)

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm not much of a Windoze guy, so tread carefully.

There appear to be about a bazillion ways to skin this particular feline of you're willing to use a third-party program, but one suggestion would be to run your app using [the native task scheduler registry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382989(v=vs.85).aspx) via an [XML file](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722156(v=ws.11).aspx).  If you set [StopOnIdleEnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383117(v=vs.85).aspx) you know you're running only when the system is idle.

It looks like you could use alien to directly call the [ITaskService interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381832(v=vs.85).aspx) directly, bit I'm guessing thats overkill here.

Of course, for this to really work you need to deal with being unceremoniously killed when the system becomes, er, unidle.  I would imagine that [winapi's wait_async](https://stevedonovan.github.io/winapi/api.html#Event:wait_async) would get triggered when this happens, but I've never used it, so *caveat emptor*.  If your program can be safely interrupted, maybe you don't care, or you can separate the volatile management program from the long-running/unsafe-to-kill child.

You could also come up with some heartbeat mechanism from the volatile manager to let the child know it's OK/not OK to continue running (e.g. a process name, a touched file, etc).